# PHP Regex: find lines of strings not wrapped in HTML tags

Tags: php, html, sanitization

I have a number of HTML files (about 500) that came from some editor wherein it sometimes did not put `<p>` tags around certain paragraphs. Instead, it seems to have used line breaks as paragraph indicators.

The problem is that the HTML files I'm working with have a mix of HTML and this odd use-line-breaks-as-paragraphs markup.

I plan to run a script in PHP that opens the HTML files one at a time, and scan it for strings that are wrapped between newlines AND do not have HTML tags surrounding them.

I think I need to use lookarounds, but my attempts aren't successful.

Assume the string:

```
<p>hello</p>
hi, world
<p>hello
world</p>
hi
, world
<p>hello <b>world</b></p>
hello</p>
<p>world
```

What I think I want out of the above sample are the two "hi, world" strings.

The regex I need I think is: the start of a line, not followed by an opening HTML tag, followed by a number of characters, not followed by a closing HTML tag, following by the end of a line.

Here's my regex so far:

```
^(?!<.*?>).*?(?!</.*?>)$
```

Unfortunately, the regex also captures strings that end in a closing HTML tag (but without an opening HTML tag).

How do I solve this problem with regex? What is going on with my regex?

Also, is there a better solution in PHP to sanitize the HTML?

Comment: You can try using DOMDocument..

Comment: What do you wish to do after detecting them?

Comment: Wrap them in p tags

Comment: Before attempting on this, I would like to say that unclosed `p` tags shouldn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse this instead of a regex as regex is too unreadable and is prone to mistakes.

To get text nodes only, run an XPATH query and replace every text node in the original dom with a newly created `p` element having the text node's value. In the end, save the HTML and you are good to go. Note that this also adds proper DOCTYPE and html tags if they aren't present before and I presume it isn't an issue for you.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // you can capture errors and do the exception handling here if the HTML is malformed. Using this for the sake of demonstration here.
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$textnodes = $xpath->query('/html/body/text()');

foreach($textnodes as $node){
  $pTag = $doc->createElement('p', $node->nodeValue);
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($pTag, $node);
}

$doc->saveHTMLFile('test.html');
```